# Compilation error..Class cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have created abstract class `Employee` and I define a method called `calculateSalary()` as an abstract method. Employee abstract class is inherited by `Contractor` & `FullTimeEmployee` classes. When I try implementation of Abstract in main class I got a compiler error that shows class cannot be resolved to a type.

1. `Employee.Class`:

```
package Abstract;

public abstract class Employee
{
    String name;
    int salaryPerHour;
    
    public Employee(String name, int salaryPerHour) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salaryPerHour = salaryPerHour;
    }
    public abstract int calculateSalary();
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getSalaryPerHour() {
        return salaryPerHour;
    }
    public void setSalaryPerHour(int salaryPerHour) {
        this.salaryPerHour = salaryPerHour;
    }
    
public class Contractor extends Employee
{
     int workingHours;
    
    public Contractor(String name, int salaryPerHour, int workingHours) {
        super(name, salaryPerHour);
        this.workingHours = workingHours;
    }

    @Override
    public int calculateSalary()
    {
        return getSalaryPerHour() * workingHours;
    }
}

public class FullTimeEmployee extends Employee
{
    public FullTimeEmployee(String name, int salaryPerHour) {
        super(name, salaryPerHour);
    }
    @Override
    public int calculateSalary()
    {
        return getSalaryPerHour() * 8;
    }
}
    
}
```

2. In `Main` class:

```
package Abstract;

public class AbstractClassExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Employee contractor = new Contractor("contractor", 10, 10);
        Employee fullTimeEmployee = new FullTimeEmployee("full time employee", 8);
        System.out.println(contractor.calculateSalary());
        System.out.println(fullTimeEmployee.calculateSalary());

    }

}
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message so that we can tell what chat class can't be found, etcetera.  Also please include the command lines that you are using to compile this code.

Comment: Did you put Employee, Contractor and FullTimeEmployee all in one .java file? Put them in separate files.

Comment: Note that it is **bad style** to have a package name that starts with a capital letter.  (And it is a bad idea to chose a name that is almost a Java keyword ... "Abstract".  Surely you can think of something more appropriate.)

Comment: `Contractor` and `FullTimeEmployee` are inside the class body of `Employee`, which makes them *nested classes*. You don't want that, so you need to move them outside, but then you'll run into the problem that you can only have 1 top-level `public` class per `.java`, which means that you need to **move them to 2 separate files: `Contractor,java` and `FullTimeEmployee.java`**

Comment: Thank you guys...i will consider all of your suggestions and i will implement it.